# Blackjack Game - displaying ASCII Graphics / Multiline Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python and currently trying to create a basic blackjack game using ASCII graphics to represent the cards. I've placed the card images in a list of multiline strings and the idea is to call the specific index for each one when a card needs to be displayed.

However I can't get them to print next to each other, and no amount of tinkering seems to get it to work. Here's the code:

```
CARDS = ['''
 -------
|K      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      K|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|Q      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      Q|
 ------- ''', ''' 
 -------
|J      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      J|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|10     |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|     10|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|9      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      9|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|8      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      8|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|7      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      7|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|6      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      6|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|5      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      5|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|6      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      6|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|5      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      5|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|4      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      4|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|3      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      3|
 ------- ''', '''
 -------
|2      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      2|
 ------- ''', ''' 
 -------
|A      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      A|
 ------- '''
]

BLANKCARD = '''
 -------
|XXXXXXX|
|XXXXXXX|
|XXXXXXX|
|XXXXXXX|
|XXXXXXX|
 ------- '''


def displayCards():
    print(CARDS[2] + CARDS[14], end='')

displayCards()
```

The above code prints the following:

```
 -------
|J      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      J|
 ------- 
 -------
|A      |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|      A|
 -------
```

I've tried using end='' to get rid of the new line, but no joy. Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can get the cards next to each other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest making an example of what you'd like to see as the output, and then look at it and consider the order that the characters need to come out - row by row. You can't just print one after the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting little problem.  Here's a quick solution that I whipped up.

`class Card:`

```
def topchar(char):
    return '|{}      |'.format(char)

def botchar(char):
    return '|      {}|'.format(char)

def print(char_list):
    top = ' ------- '
    side ='|       |'
    topout = ''
    topchar = ''
    botchar = ''
    blankside = ''
    for char in char_list:
            topout += top + ' '
            topchar += Card.topchar(char) + ' '
            blankside += side + ' '
            botchar += Card.botchar(char) + ' '
    print(topout)
    print(topchar)
    print(blankside)
    print(blankside)
    print(blankside)
    print(botchar)
    print(topout)
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem though. It streamlines the creation of cards, but doesn't seem to do anything for the main problem.

Comment: My understanding is that the problem is printing the cards next to one another.  This accomplishes that.

Comment: Oh does it? Sorry then. Ill read the code over again. At first glance it seemed to just print a card.

Comment: Cool, this looks very similar to something I started attempting after reading the comments, although yours seems much more succinct. Thank you!

Comment: how would this work? do you call he Card.print and give it a list of cards, say maybe Card.print([CARDS[0], CARDS[1]]) and it will print em one next to the other

Comment: Yeah, any iterable of characters should work `Card.print('abcdefg')`

Answer (score 2):

With the way you're doing it, that would be very difficult. When you write

```
end=''
```

That only gets rid of the newline at the very end of the printed text. The problem is, every one of your cards has a new line on the right side:

```
 -------
|J      |
|       |
|       | # <--- Newline here
|       |
|      J|
 -------
```

You would need to create a function that takes a list of cards, and creates one long line of them. That will be a solid project in its own. You would have to take the strings that make up the cards, cut them into lines (cut on each new line), place all the corresponding lines together, getting rid of the newlines in between, then glue all the pieces together. I might actually try this for a morning project now.

And instead of hard coding all the cards like you have, create a function that you give a card value to, and it creates a card for you.

Comment: Or line n of a card, given n

Comment: @greggo There's a lot of possible ways to do it, but none of them would really be easy. I've considered trying to create a program that places ascii graphics side by side, but it's not easy unless you have a guarantee that they're all the same size.

Comment: But we have that guarantee here. And we have `zip(CARDS[i].split('\n') for i in hand)` or something like that

Comment: @greggo Ya, you're right, it might be easier. I'm on my phone, and haven't written Python in awhile though, so I don't want to half-ass a solution. You could post that as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you write a function that, given i and n, returns a string which represents line i of card n. You can then call that in a double nested loop, printing the results in sequence, to get the result you need. 
You can start by making an example of the output you want to see, to use as a reference while coding the loop.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I didn't know about the zip() function either. What about having two lists of ASCII images representing the tops and bottoms of the card, then using zip() to iterate through each list and concatenate them into the same print function, so they can just sit side by side on the same line? If that makes sense?